# Do I need hreflang x-default and can I've multiple hreflang point to same URL?

Tags: seo, multilingual, ietf-bcp-47

Based on the [Google info about `hreflang`](http://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en), I came up with this but I've the `en` and default point to same URL instead of having another `en/`. Will that be fine? I don't want to create another folder as it require additional maintenance.

Basically, the default and main site is in English. If user needs to see the other language they just go to extra folder `zh-*`.

```
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com” hreflang=”en”>

<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/zh-hant” hreflang=”zh-Hant”>

<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/zh-hanz” hreflang=”zh-Hans”>

<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com” hreflang=”x-default”>
```

Also is it okay I make it short in the URL to have `zh-hant` to `cht` and `zh-hans` to `chs`?

Comment: Note that you are using incorrect quotation marks (you should use `"` or `'` instead of `”`).

Answer (score 0):

If English is default, you don't need to state English alternative. Only default is enough.

For the URLs, it's up to you. You can do whatever you like.

Comment: Hi Bojan, can you source that ?

Comment: Yoast recommends including both x-default and a language-specific default. https://yoast.com/hreflang-ultimate-guide/#x-default